# Leibniz formula for π - Is this any good? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing an exercise that asks for a function that approximates the value of pi using Leibniz' formula. These are the explanations on Wikipedia:

[image]

[image]

Logical thinking comes to me easily, but I wasn't given much of a formal education in maths, so I'm a bit lost as to what the leftmost symbols in the second one represent. I tried to make the code `pi = ( (-1)**n / (2*n + 1) ) * 4`, but that returned `1.9999990000005e-06` instead of 3.14159..., so I used an accumulator pattern instead (since the chapter of the guide that this was in mentions them as well) and it worked fine. However, I can't help thinking that it's somewhat contrived and there's probably a better way to do it, given Python's focus on simplicity and making programmes as short as possible. This is the full code:

```
def myPi(n):
    denominator = 1
    addto = 1

    for i in range(n):
        denominator = denominator + 2
        addto = addto - (1/denominator)
        denominator = denominator + 2
        addto = addto + (1/denominator)

    pi = addto * 4

    return(pi)

print(myPi(1000000))
```

Does anyone know a better function?

Comment: That stands for - *calculate the summation of the attached expression for n = 0 to Infinity*

Comment: You'll find that the biggest problem [isn't the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yeah, floating point numbers have given me more than one headache since I got into this.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It’s a really terrible algorithm, though. Converges incredibly slowly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capital sigma here is [sigma notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation). It is notation used to represent a summation in concise form.

So your sum is actually an infinite sum. The first term, for n=0, is:

```
(-1)**0/(2*0+1)
```

This is added to

```
(-1)**1/(2*1+1)
```

and then to

```
(-1)**2/(2*2+1)
```

and so on for ever. The summation is what is known mathematically as a *convergent sum*.

In Python you would write it like this:

```
def estimate_pi(terms):
    result = 0.0
    for n in range(terms):
        result += (-1.0)**n/(2.0*n+1.0)
    return 4*result
```

If you wanted to optimise a little, you can avoid the exponentiation.

```
def estimate_pi(terms):
    result = 0.0
    sign = 1.0
    for n in range(terms):
        result += sign/(2.0*n+1.0)
        sign = -sign
    return 4*result

....

>>> estimate_pi(100)
3.1315929035585537
>>> estimate_pi(1000)
3.140592653839794
```

Answer (score 6):

The Leibniz formula translates directly into Python with no muss or fuss:

```
>>> steps = 1000000
>>> sum((-1.0)**n / (2.0*n+1.0) for n in reversed(range(steps))) * 4
3.1415916535897934
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Python you can do something like:

```
def term(n):
    return ( (-1.)**n / (2.*n + 1.) )*4.

def pi(nterms):
    return sum(map(term,range(nterms)))
```

and then calculate `pi` with the number of terms you need to reach a given precision:

```
pi(100)
# 3.13159290356

pi(1000)
# 3.14059265384
```

Answer (score 0):

The following version uses Ramanujan's formula as outlined in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/motivation-for-ramanujans-mysterious-pi-formula) SO post - it uses a relation between pi and the "monster group", as discussed in [this article](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0013).

```
import math

def Pi(x):
    Pi = 0
    Add = 0
    for i in range(x):
        Add =(math.factorial(4*i) * (1103 + 26390*i))/(((math.factorial(i))**4)*(396**(4*i)))
        Pi = Pi + (((math.sqrt(8))/(9801))*Add)
    Pi = 1/Pi
    print(Pi)

Pi(100)
```

Comment: The monster group ... something that always keeps me active in maths.

Answer (score 0):

This was my approach:

```
def estPi(terms):
    outPut = 0.0
    for i in range (1, (2 * terms), 4):
        outPut = (outPut + (1/i) - (1/(i+2)))
    return 4 * outPut
```

I take in the number of terms the user wants, then in the for loop I double it to account for only using odds.

```
at 100 terms I get        3.1315929035585537
at 1000 terms I get       3.140592653839794
at 10000 terms I get      3.1414926535900345
at 100000 terms I get     3.1415826535897198
at 1000000 terms I get    3.1415916535897743
at 10000000 terms I get   3.1415925535897915
at 100000000 terms I get  3.141592643589326
at 1000000000 terms I get 3.1415926525880504
Actual Pi is              3.1415926535897932
```

Got to love a convergent series.

Answer (score 0):

```
def myPi(iters):
    pi = 0
    sign = 1
    denominator = 1

    for i in range(iters):
        pi = pi + (sign/denominator)
        # alternating between negative and positive
        sign = sign * -1
        denominator = denominator + 2

    pi = pi * 4.0
    return pi

pi_approx = myPi(10000)
print(pi_approx)
```

Answer (score 0):

old thread, but i wanted to stuff around with this and coincidentally i came up with pretty much the same as user3220980

```
# gregory-leibnitz
# pi acurate to 8 dp in around 80 sec
# pi to 5 dp in .06 seconds
import time
start_time = time.time()

pi = 4 # start at 4
times = 100000000

for i in range(3,times,4):
        pi -= (4/i) + (4/(i + 2))
    
print(pi)
print("{} seconds".format(time.time() - start_time))
```